# Pass $sSymbol an input parameter to a Class

Tags: php

I got this class code from https://github.com/ricardotiago/sec-gov-api, which is used to retrieve and parse quarterly and yearly reports from the U.S Securities Exchange website.I do not understand how to print the results and what sort of parameters it's accepts. Is$sSmbol an input parameter, how do I pass this parameter so that it displays the quarterly and yearly report

```
   <?php
    require_once "parallelCurl.php";
    class SecGovAPI {
      const SEARCH_LINK = "http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar";
      const BASE_LINK = "http://www.sec.gov/";
      const QUARTERLY_REPORT = '10-Q';
      const YEARLY_REPORT = '10-K';
      const MOST_RECENT_REPORT = 0;
      const ALL_REPORTS = 1;
      public function __construct($sSymbol) {
        $this->oParallelCurl = new ParallelCurl();
        $this->sSymbol = $sSymbol;
        $this->oDoc = new DOMDocument();
        $this->report = array();
      }
      public function getQuaterlyReport($iSearchType = SecGovAPI::MOST_RECENT_REPORT) {
        if ($iSearchType !== SecGovAPI::MOST_RECENT_REPORT && $iSearchType !== SecGovAPI::ALL_REPORTS) {
          return array();
        }
        $aReportLinks = $this->search(SecGovAPI::QUARTERLY_REPORT, $iSearchType);
        var_dump($aReportLinks);
        foreach ($aReportLinks as $link) {
          $this->oParallelCurl->addUrl(SecGovAPI::BASE_LINK."/".$link);
        }
        $aData = $this->oParallelCurl->run();
        foreach ($aData as $link => $xml) {
          $this->oDoc->loadXML($xml);
          $oXPath = new DOMXPath($this->oDoc);
          $oXPath->registerNamespace("xbrli", "http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance");
          $this->getReportData($oXPath, $link, "dei:EntityCommonStockSharesOutstanding", "CommonStockSharesOutstanding");
          $this->getReportData($oXPath, $link, "us-gaap:NetIncomeLoss", "NetIncomeLoss");
       }
        var_dump($this->report);
      }
      public function getYearlyReport($iSearchType = SecGovAPI::MOST_RECENT_REPORT) {
        if ($iSearchType !== SecGovAPI::MOST_RECENT_REPORT && $iSearchType !== SecGovAPI::ALL_REPORTS) {
          return array();
        }
        $aReportLinks = $this->search(SecGovAPI::YEARLY_REPORT, $iSearchType);
        var_dump($aReportLinks);
        foreach ($aReportLinks as $link) {
          $this->oParallelCurl->addUrl(SecGovAPI::BASE_LINK."/".$link);
        }
        $aData = $this->oParallelCurl->run();
        foreach ($aData as $link => $xml) {
          $this->oDoc->loadXML($xml);
          $oXPath = new DOMXPath($this->oDoc);
          $oXPath->registerNamespace("xbrli", "http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance");
          $this->getReportData($oXPath, $link, "dei:EntityCommonStockSharesOutstanding", "CommonStockSharesOutstanding");
          $this->getReportData($oXPath, $link, "us-gaap:NetIncomeLoss", "NetIncomeLoss");
        }
        var_dump($this->report);
      }
      public function getReportData($oXPath, $link, $sEntity, $sSaveAs) {
        $oNodelist = $oXPath->query("//xbrli:xbrl/".$sEntity);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $oNodelist->length; $i++) {
          $this->report[$link][$sSaveAs][$i] = $oNodelist->item($i)->nodeValue;
        }
      }
      protected function search($sType, $iSearchType) {
        $aParams = array("company" => "",
                         "match" => "",
                         "CIK" => $this->sSymbol,
                         "filenum" => "",
                         "State" => "",
                         "Country" => "",
                         "SIC" => "",
                         "count" => "40",
                         "owner" => "exclude",
                         "Find" => "Find Companies",
                         "action" => "getcompany",
                         "type" => $sType,
                         "output" => "atom");
        $sUrl = SecGovAPI::SEARCH_LINK . "?". http_build_query($aParams);
        $this->oDoc->load($sUrl);
        $oXPath = new DOMXPath($this->oDoc);
        $oXPath->registerNamespace("atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
        $aLinks = $this->getReportLinks($oXPath, $iSearchType);
        $aReportLinks = array();
        foreach ($aLinks as $link) {
          $this->oParallelCurl->addUrl($link);
        }
        $aHtmls = $this->oParallelCurl->run();
        foreach ($aHtmls as $html) {
          $this->oDoc->loadHTML($html);
          $oXPath = new DOMXPath($this->oDoc);
          $oNodeList = $oXPath->query('//table[@summary="Data Files"]/tr[2]/td[3]/a');
          if ($oNodeList->length === 0) continue;
          $aReportLinks[] = $oNodeList->item(0)->getAttribute("href");
        }
        return $aReportLinks;
      }
      protected function getReportLinks($oXPath, $iSearchType) {
        if ($iSearchType === SecGovAPI::MOST_RECENT_REPORT) {
          $aNodeList = $oXPath->query("//atom:feed/atom:entry[1]/atom:link");
          if ($aNodeList->length === 1) 
            return array($aNodeList->item(0)->getAttribute("href"));
          else 
            return null;
        }
        else if ($iSearchType === SecGovAPI::ALL_REPORTS) {
          $aNodeList = $oXPath->query("//atom:feed/atom:entry/atom:link");
          for ($i = 0; $i < $aNodeList->length; $i++) {
            $aReportLinks[] = $aNodeList->item($i)->getAttribute("href");
          }
          return $aReportLinks;
        }
        else return null;
      }
      protected function getAccessionNumber($oXPath, $iSearchType) {
        if ($iSearchType === SecGovAPI::MOST_RECENT_REPORT) {
          $aNodeList = $oXPath->query("//atom:feed/atom:entry[1]/atom:id");
          if ($aNodeList->length === 1) $sRawAccessNumber = $aNodeList->item(0)->nodeValue;
          else return null;
          return $this->processAccessionNumber($sRawAccessNumber);
        }
        else if ($iSearchType === SecGovAPI::ALL_REPORTS) {
          $aNodeList = $oXPath->query("//atom:feed/atom:entry/atom:id");
          for ($i = 0; $i < $aNodeList->length; $i++) {
            $sRawAccessNumber = $aNodeList->item($i)->nodeValue;
            $aAccessionNumber[] = $this->processAccessionNumber($sRawAccessNumber);
          }
          return $aAccessionNumber; 
        }
        else return null;
      }
      protected function processAccessionNumber($sRawAccessNumber) {
        $aSplitData = preg_split('/accession-number=/', $sRawAccessNumber);
        if (!isset($aSplitData[1])) return null;
        $sAccessionNumber = str_replace('-','', $aSplitData[1]);
        return $sAccessionNumber;
      }
      protected function getReportDate($oXPath, $iSearchType) {
        if ($iSearchType === SecGovAPI::MOST_RECENT_REPORT) {
          $aNodeList = $oXPath->query("//atom:feed/atom:entry[1]/atom:updated");
          if ($aNodeList->length === 1) 
            return $sUpdated = $aNodeList->item(0)->nodeValue;
          else 
            return null;
        }
        else if ($iSearchType === SecGovAPI::ALL_REPORTS) {
          $aNodeList = $oXPath->query("//atom:feed/atom:entry/atom:updated");
          for ($i = 0; $i < $aNodeList->length; $i++) {
            $aUpdated[] = $aNodeList->item($i)->nodeValue;
          }
          return $aUpdated; 
        }
        else return null;
      }
    }
    ?>
```

**parallelCurl.php**

```
<?php
class ParallelCurl {
  protected $aHandlers;
  public function __construct() {
    $this->aHandlers = array();
    $this->rMultiHandler = curl_multi_init();
  }
  public function addUrl($sUrl) {
    $rHandler = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($rHandler, CURLOPT_URL, $sUrl);
    curl_setopt($rHandler, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($rHandler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_multi_add_handle($this->rMultiHandler, $rHandler);    
    $this->aHandlers[$sUrl] = $rHandler;
  }
  public function run() {
    $blsRunning = null;
    do {
      $rHandler = curl_multi_exec($this->rMultiHandler, $blsRunning);
    } while ($rHandler === CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    while ($blsRunning && $rHandler == CURLM_OK) {
      if (curl_multi_select($this->rMultiHandler) != -1) {
        do {
          $rHandler = curl_multi_exec($this->rMultiHandler, $blsRunning);
        } while ($rHandler == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
      }
    }
    foreach ($this->aHandlers as $url => $handler) {
      $data[$url] = curl_multi_getcontent($handler);
      curl_multi_remove_handle($this->rMultiHandler, $handler);
    }

    $this->aHandlers = array();
    return $data;
  }
  public function __destruct() {
    curl_multi_close($this->rMultiHandler);
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: `echo SecGovAPI::YEARLY_REPORT;` ?

Comment: @Federico $sSymbol has to be passed so that it returns the data

Comment: `echo self::YEARLY_REPORT;`

Comment: sorry if i have confused you, I  would like to print the report so if i pass symbol=msft it retireves the data,

Comment: @Marcus Fatal error: Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active in

Comment: I'm not sure that I've understand what you want do to

Comment: Where are you instantiating the class?

Comment: @Federico i updated the question, sorry for the mess

Comment: @Marcus updated the question, sorry for the mess, please check

Comment: `$class = new SecGovAPI('your_sSymbol_here); echo $class->getQuaterlyReport(); echo $class->getYearlyReport();` ?

Comment: @Federico that worked :), how do i accept your answder

Comment: I'm not sure that someone should answer it, it's probably a duplicate question anyhow. If you want you can delete it

Comment: Its not duplicate now

Comment: okay, since it's not a problem for you I've submitted the answer

Comment: @Federico accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an instance of the `SecGovAPI` class you can use the `new` keyword:

```
$class = new SecGovAPI($sSymbol);
```

then you can call the methods `getQuaterlyReport` and `getYearlyReport` with:

```
echo $class->getQuaterlyReport();
```

```
echo $class->getYearlyReport();
```

Both these methods has an argument, and by default is `SecGovAPI::MOST_RECENT_REPORT`. You can also use:

- `SecGovAPI::QUARTERLY_REPORT`
- `SecGovAPI::YEARLY_REPORT`
- `SecGovAPI::ALL_REPORTS`

Example:

```
echo $class->getQuaterlyReport(SecGovAPI::QUARTERLY_REPORT);
```